# Convex Subset of Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Please help me understand why a particular statement follows from this lemma.

Lemma: Let $K$ be a convex subset of Hilbert Space $H$ and $p$ $\in$ $H$. Suppose that $q$ $\in$ $K$ is such that dist($p$,$K$)$=$$\parallel$$p$$-$$q$$\parallel$ (where dist($p$,$K$) $:=$ inf$\parallel$$p$$-$$q$$\parallel$, $q$ $\in$ $K$). Then Re$\langle$$p-q,q'-q$$\rangle$$\leq$$0$ $\forall$$q'$$\in$$K$

Statement: In the case that $K$ is a linear subspace of $H$, then Re$\langle$$p-q,q'-q$$\rangle$$\leq$$0$ $\forall$$q'$$\in$$K$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\langle$$p-q,q'$$\rangle$ $=$ $0$ $\forall$$q'$$\in$$K$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It doesn't follow from the lemma, the statement is valid in itself. Note that since $q\in K$, if $K$ is a subspace, $q'-q$ also runs over $K$.

Comment: Thank you, I can now see that the left hand side follows from the right hand side. I'm still not seeing how to go from an inequality only considering the real part, to an equality considering the whole inner product though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $y:=p-q$. For all $x\in K$ we have 
$$Re\langle y,x\rangle, \ Re\langle y, -x\rangle, \ Re\langle y, ix\rangle, \ Re\langle y, -ix\rangle \ \le 0\,.$$

Comment: I now have it with your hint if the idea was to show Im$\langle$$y,x$$\rangle$$\leq$$0$, $-$Im$\langle$$y,x$$\rangle$$\leq$$0$ and conclude Im$\langle$$y,x$$\rangle$ $=0$ (same for Re$\langle$$y,x$$\rangle$ $=0$).